# Git erroneous commit... Not pushed, but cannot reset or revert

Tags: git

I clearly screwed up and would like to use this as a learning experience.

I had numerous code changes since last push (bad practice I know, and I've learned), but here's where I'm at.  I was trying to do grouped commits instead of everything at once.   So I committed the first code file/unit of work and that was fine.  Then when I was doing the second, I forgot to stage it.  Entered my message and Committed (oops!  Every change was part of this one commit!).  Did a revert on the second commit, but my local code was not restored to the state prior to the commit.

Looked up here and did a reset to the first good commit... but still the changes in the other files are all missing.

Tried a reset to HEAD~1 as noted here and still the changes to all the files are not showing up.

Is there any way to get the entire solution (all the changes) back to where they were before this screwup???

UPDATE... I just did a reset to the second commit (the one with everything) and it got my code back...  I may just suck it up and leave all the files in a single commit (I'm the only developer anyway), but don't like doing that (OCD!)

Comment: I'm confused. If you didn't stage anything there was nothing to commit. My understanding is that you'd have had to use the `--allow-empty` flag. Are you misinterpreting what actually happened?

Comment: Using VS2022, the option was to commit all changes -- that's when I realized I'd not selected the files. :)

Comment: If you want `git diff` to show all of the changes just before the erroneous commit, switch to the erroneous commit and try: `git reset --mixed HEAD~1`

Comment: let me provide an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose your history looks like this at the moment

```
* FFF crap 3 (some-branch -> HEAD)
* EEE crap 2
* DDD crap 1
* CCC second commit with everything else instead of broken pieces
* BBB first commit
* AAA last commit in another branch
```

Then you can do this:

```
git reset --hard CCC # go back to the commit where you committed everything. Use with care. any uncommitted things in your working tree will be wiped
```

Now it is like this:

```
* CCC second commit with everything else instead of broken pieces (some-branch -> HEAD)
* BBB first commit
* AAA last commit in another branch
```

Now do this:

```
git reset --soft @~
git reset .
```

And now it's like this:

```
* BBB first commit  (some-branch -> HEAD)
* AAA last commit in another branch
```

And all that you had committed in CCC will be laying around your working tree ready like CCC did not happen at all.

Now, as my final tip, go check how to use `git reset --soft` and `git commit --amend` as they are major time (and life) savers.

Comment: perfect!  Thank you... I'd gotten to the DETACHED HEAD doing the reset hard, but could not bring it all back together... Lifesaver!!!

Comment: `git reset --hard` will not get you in `detached HEAD` state... probably you had checked out a commit already before doing the reset.

Answer (score 2):

My first advide here would be to not rush into harmful commands, especially `reset --hard` from the beginning. Cases in which one can really loose data are very rare with Git, but it seems that most of the people directly focus on them when they struggle to achieve a given goal.

When you forget to ship something into your last commit (which often happens), simply add this content then use `git commit --amend`. This allows you to amend this commit, which actually places you back at edition time with an updated index and the last message you recorded. This enables you indeed to both amend this message and/or the commit's content. What Git actually does here is spawning another commit replacing the previous one.

If you forgot something on a previous commit, which is not so far but not among the very last ones neither, the easiest way to fix this is by using `rebase -i` command, associated to `squash` option.

**Remark**: one may frequently read that `rebase -i` is meant to rewrite a branch. That's not exactly true. Just like a regular rebase, an *interactive* rebase is supposed to "rebase" a branch onto another starting point, but the facilities offered by `-i` are so useful that developers often rebase "onto the very same place" just to take advantage of these side effects.

So, in order to rebuild an history that includes what you missed, you just need to:

- Commit what you needed to include into a dedicated commit on top of your branch, named "*omitted stuff*" or something;
- Use `git tag imessedituphere` so you can easily to back to this point if this procedure fails too;
- Verify that your repository is clean using `git status`;
- Do `git rebase -i <some commit id on the branch before things went wrong>`;
- Let Git present you the list of these commits in historical order;
- Reorder these row if needed, so your commits will be too;
- Move the last `row` (omitted stuff) in the list to insert it just after the row referencing the commit that was supposed to include this stuff;
- Replace the `edit` keyword aside this row (omitted stuff) with `squash`;
- Save and exit your editor to start the procedure.

`squash` will actually merge your commit with the previous one, acting roughly the same way that `--amend` will. You then will get to an editor page that will present both the message of original commit and squashed one, concatenated, which will let to free to keep only what's really relevant (you could even take advantage of this step to perform extra amendments but we'll let this point aside for now).